# Checkbox valiadtion using Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

I am using Angular js, in which i have a textbox and collection of checkbox. I want to check if atleast one checkbox is checked when the submit button is clicked. Below is the existing code:

```
<form name="mainForm" id="createForm" ng-submit="mainForm.$valid && add()" novalidate>
        <div ng-controller="testController" ng-init="init()">    

    <div>
                        <label>Name :</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" maxlength="150" required ng-model="testName" name="testName" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.testName.$error.required">Name is required</span>
                <br />
            <div class="row">
                    <div>
                        <label>Delivery Method</label>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="method in deliveryMethods">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="{{method.id}}"
                               value="{{method.value}}" name="deliveryMethod[]" ng-model="method.selected"
                               ng-click="toggleSelection(method.value)" ng-required="value.length==0"> {{method.value}}
                    </div>
                </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submitted=true"/>
```

How to achieve this in angular js?
Thanks

Comment: do you want to disable button if no checkbox is checked?

Comment: Can you add the deliveryMethods array in the question please ?

Comment: You can refer my example here -  https://plnkr.co/edit/iH0uzhoHUTPFXH0g8Hyk?p=preview

Comment: Looks like it works. I get an error unless I check one of the checkboxes. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi Sumit, the demo works, however, i do not want to show the error message on checkbox unchecked.. The message should be shown only on submit button click event. Initially in demo, the message is not shown. without selecting any checkbox, i click submit, i get error message. this is correct. Now I check one checkbox, and uncheck it. Now thwe error message shows. can the message be shown only on submit button click event. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I tried the plnk code, but giving error in page load. Error is: TypeError: Object.keys: argument is not an Object
   at $scope.someSelected (http://site/abs.js:558:9). Below is the code used:

Comment: <div ng-repeat="method in deliveryMethods">
<input type="checkbox" id="{{method.id}}" value="{{method.value}}" name="deliveryMethod[]" ng-model="method.selected"
ng-click="toggleSelection(method.value)" ng-required="!someSelected(method.value)"> {{method.value}}                     </div>